# scanf char* word in struct shows only the last input

Tags: c, struct, char, scanf

I am only allowed to use following headers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and I defined my `struct student` as following:

```
struct dict
{
    char* word;
    struct dict* link;
};
```

There are many functions, but only one function that I have problem right now.
This function inserts a struct dict with certain name at the end of the link.

```
struct student *Linsert(struct dict *list, char *name)
{
    struct student *pnew;
    struct student *pn;
    int exist = 1;

    pnew = (struct dict *)malloc(sizeof(struct dict));
    pnew -> next = NULL;
    pnew -> name = name;

    if (list != NULL)
    {
        for (pn = list; pn -> next != NULL; pn = pn -> next) ;
        pn -> next = pnew;
    }
    else
        list = pnew;

    return list;
}
```

Using the following function,

> ```
> //print all the values in the list
> void printList(struct dict* list);
> ```

I did this:

```
int main(void)
{

    struct dict *list = NULL;

    char *name;

    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", name);
        if (name == 'Q')
            break;

        list = Linsert(list, name);
        printList(list);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Lets say for input, I typed three
`apple` `banana` and `orange`, my result shows three of my last input.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Always compile with **all warnings** and do not ignore any of them.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), in particular how to format code blocks, for next time.

Comment: @KerrekSB `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` always results in forcibly better code `:)`

Comment: Is this actual code? Your struct has `struct dict* link` but your code uses `-> next`. This should not have compiled. _Please_ copy and paste code, don't retype it...

Comment: This looks kind of like homework.  Also, this is a good place to get out a debugger (such as gdb) and step though your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` snippet alone has a whole bunch of problems:

- `name` is an uninitialized pointer; it's pointing to some unknown location in memory that you haven't allocated and are allowed to use, therefore causing undefined behaviour. Perhaps you want `char name[20]` to allocate an array of 20 `char`s on the stack, and have `scanf` store the input in this buffer.
- You're comparing a `char*` (a pointer to the start of a string) to a single `char` `'Q'` - you're comparing a pointer and an integer value as your compiler warnings will tell you. You're not comparing the contents of the string for the value `'Q'`, you're comparing the memory address of `name` and the integer value for `'Q'`. If you want to compare the string `name` with the string `"Q"`, use `strcmp` and check for a return value of 0.

You also want to be making a copy of the variable passed to `Linsert` otherwise, as you've noticed, you'll be passing a pointer to the same location in memory every time, and a change to this block of memory will change each of your items.

If you turn your compiler warnings up you'll get even more warnings.

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems with your code:

- You need to pass `scanf` a `char` array of size sufficient to store the input string, not simply a char pointer.
- You need to copy strings passed into `Linsert` (use `strdup`).

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating any memory for the name, so scanf is writing to some random location, and overwriting that every time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you've not allocated storage for the `word` member to point to.  You have also not allocated space for `name` to point at.  That is a principle cause of trouble.

You need to allocate space for `name`; the easiest way is:

```
char name[128];
```

You need to allocate space to store the word, and you need to copy the contents of `name` into the `word` so that when the next line overwrites `name`, it does not destroy the saved `word`.

Adapting your code, you might use:

```
struct student *Linsert(struct dict *list, char *name)
{
    struct student *pnew;
    struct student *pn;

    pnew = (struct dict *)malloc(sizeof(struct dict));
    if (pnew == 0)
        ...error...
    pnew->next = NULL;
    pnew->word = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    if (pnew->word == 0)
        ...error...
    strcpy(pnew->word, name);

    if (list != NULL)
    {
        for (pn = list; pn->next != NULL; pn = pn->next)
            ;
        pn->next = pnew;
    }
    else
        list = pnew;

    return list;
}
```

Do not omit the error checks on memory allocation - painful though it be.  It will bite you when you forget.

Stylistically, do not use spaces around either `->` or `.`; they are operators that bind very tightly, and they should not be spaced out like other binary operators.

There's a convenient function, `strdup()`, the duplicates a string, but it is not standard C (it is standard POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

Since `name` is a char pointer, your assignment to the field of each `dict` struct will use the latest value it points to.